# Using ADF, get the Latest Folder based on Timestamp in Folder Name

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Lets say in ADLS Gen2 there are multiple Folders in a RootFolder, where Folder name is Timestamp.

Using Azure Data Factory, How would you get the Latest Folder based on Folder Name(ie. where the folder name is having latest timestamp).
I know this could be easily done with Python or Shell Script, But How would this be done by specifically

Example -

Folder Structure :

```
RootFolder
    |- 20210921131200
    |- 20210920120000
    |- 20210801021345
```

In the above case, It should return Folder 20210921131200 as its the latest Timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create 2 variables (ex: check_date & latest_folder) and assign a sample minimum date value in the check_date variable to compare it with the folder date, and store the result in the other variable latest_folder.

[image]

2. Using `Get Metadata` activity, get the list of folder names under the RootFolder.

[image]

**Output** of Get Metadata:

[image]

3. Pass the output of `Get Metadata` activity to `ForEach` activity.

`@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childitems`

[image]

4. Inside `ForEach` activity, using `If Condition` activity check, the current folder name of ForEach is greater than the **check_date** variable value.

`@greater(int(item().name),int(variables('check_date')))`

[image]

5. `If condition` is true, then pass the current item to the check_date variable. This will replace the sample value with the folder name.

[image]

6. After looping all the folders, using Set variable activity, pass the check_date value to the latest_folder variable to get the latest folder name.

[image]

**Output** of Set Metadata2 holds the latest folder value in the **latest_folder** variable.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `Get Metadata` activity and loops to find this

**Example:**

Sample folders:

[image]

Dataset for ParentFolder (in your case it is RootFolder )

[image: RootFolder]

**1.** use `Get Metadata` activity to list the child folders under root folder

[image]

**2.** For each of the received `childitems`, inside `foreach activity` , append the folder names to a variable as **int array**.

```
@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems
```

[image]

**3.** lastly... identify the max value to get the latest folder

```
@string(max(variables('lastmodified')))
```

[image]

[image]