# How to use variable in ADF pipeline's copy activity source

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am creating ADF(V2) pipeline where I have to find the latest folder, based on datetime and copy all the files to destination with the same folder path

for example, if I have source path a/b/c which has folders

```
20221021010000
20221021020000
20221021030000
```

When the pipeline runs, I have to copy the latest folder (20221021030000) to destination a/b/c/20221021030000

I already figured out how to find latest folder as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70055595/using-adf-get-the-latest-folder-based-on-timestamp-in-folder-name) article, and the variable is being set correctly.

But I don't know how to use this variable in ADF copy's source. I already tried it this way, where I am using  list of files and passing the variable

[image]

When I run the pipeline, it succeeds. The copy stage gets this as input

```
{
    "source": {
        "type": "BinarySource",
        "storeSettings": {
            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
            "fileListPath": "a/b/c/20221021030000/",
            "deleteFilesAfterCompletion": false
        },
        "formatSettings": {
            "type": "BinaryReadSettings"
        }
    },
    "sink": {
        "type": "BinarySink",
        "storeSettings": {
            "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
        }
    },
    "enableStaging": false
}
```

But nothing gets copied. What would be wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to repro this. When I set file path type as List of files, and path to the list is given as below, files are not copied from source folder to sink.
[image]
[image]

**Solution:**

- In order to solve this, I set file path type as **file path in dataset**.

[image]

- In Source dataset, file path is given as in below image.

`src/@{variables('var1')}`
[image]

- All files from Source are copied to sink folder.
  [image]

Comment: Very good explanation in topics uncommon like that